# Run simple bash script to start applications at login

Tags: bash, login, command-line, gnome-terminal

I want to run a simple bash script automatically when I log in. For example

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start spotify"
gnome-terminal -e spotify --title spotify
```

When I run this command, one `gnome-terminal` shows up and `spotify` show up. I also want the gnome-terminal to popup "hidden" in a different virtual desktop. (one of the other four virtual desktops you can choose from taskbar)

I tried to add this to `/home/me/.bash_login` or something, but that didn't work..

Comment: You should use `.bashrc` or `.profile`. However, that's not good for starting programs on graphical login. There is an application for configuring startup applications.

Comment: @Olli, that starts it _every time_ you open a Terminal window :)

Comment: @Stefano: or when you login from console, or over ssh. Whenever your shell is started. That's why I said "that's not good..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to *System → Preferences → Startup Applications*, then click *Add*. Under *Command* just enter `spotify`, instead of the script. There's no need to start a terminal for it.

[image: screenshot, startup application preferences]

If you need the output, you can change your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start spotify"
spotify > /home/username/spotify.log
```

and set *it* as the command, rather than Spotify itself.

Make sure the script is *executable* by opening the file's properties, going to permissions and setting "Allow executing file as program".

Comment: There might be multiple reasons for terminal. For example debug messages.

Comment: @Olli, Thank you, I've edited my answer accordingly. This seems to me like the proper solution.

Comment: yes, definitely. And of course you should use `~` instead of static path, so it'll work with any user :)