# How can I set Ask Ubuntu website as Desktop live wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Active Web Site as Gnome Background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26017/active-web-site-as-gnome-background)

I want to use Ask Ubuntu or OMG!Ubuntu website as live desktop wallpaper. I want to see the live updates of any of the selected site as my desktop wallpaper, so that I can see the updates regularly on my desktop no need of browser to open.

I don't want any other application like screenlet. It's a different way like widgets. I want website to be integrated as desktop wallpaper though it may not be interacted but can display live updates.

I want website to show updates as I see in the browser even though I won't interact with them. But the website should be displayed as active wallpaper. I remember I used to set a website as active desktop background in Windows 98 and XP.

Is there any way to set a website as desktop live background?

Comment: I have seen the duplicate link given above but it not a answer.It says install screenlet which i dont want. I want it works well on 12.04LTS and not 10.04 version

Comment: @AthloX: Yes its clearer. My thoughts are you have 2 objectives. 1 Set a website as a desktop background (see duplicate question pointed out by con-f-use)  2: Get live feeds to your desktop without opening a browser. I think you need to decide which of these objectives are more important to you as I dont believe you can have both.